# Escaping ' in Ruby string, without escaping \ for inserting to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, escaping, gsub, single-quotes

I have a string in Ruby of the form: `"Henry's string"`

Every `gsub` and `tr` I've tried gives me forms like `"Henry\\'s string"`, `"Henry\\\\'s string"`, etc.

These are all escaping the backslashes, but leaving me with an unescaped single quote.

I've tried:

- `"Henry's string".gsub("'","\\\\'")` with varying numbers of \
- `"Henry's string".gsub(/'/) {|x| "\\\\#{x}"}` again with varying numbers of \
- `"Henry's string".gsub(/'/) {|x| "\\#{x}"}.gsub(/\\/) {|x| "#{x}"}`

I think I need an odd number of `\` to fully escape the ' (in order to load to MySQL) but I cannot figure out how to get this.

Comment: What do you want your output string to be?

Answer (score 6):

When inserting into a database, like MySQL, it's important to use **prepared statements with placeholder values**. I've put that in bold because it's extra super important to understand. All it takes is one little slip and you've created a [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/) anyone can exploit and these can be extremely damaging.

Escaping a string might seem superficially simple, but it's not. There's a lot of quirky edge cases you'll need to cover off, the details of which are too complicated to mention here in a short answer.

The simple solution is to not bother escaping at all, instead write queries of this form:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (?)
```

Where the `?` represents the data you're inserting. You can use these with, for example, the [`mysql2` driver](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) like this:

```
stmt = @client.prepare("INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (?)")
stmt.execute("Henry's string")
```

Where that driver will take care of properly encoding the values so you don't have to worry about it.

You can also use something like [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org) or [ActiveRecord](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) that simplify things even further.

Comment: But if you must use string operations, at least use `@client.escape` rather than attempting to do it by hand with `String#gsub` so you'll get it right.

Comment: @muistooshort Emphasis on *if* and *must*, but yes, that!